# How can I get HttpServletRequest Object in Jodd action class?

Tags: java, jodd

I am using `Jodd Madvoc` MVC Framework. I want to get IP address of web application client. How can I get `HttpServletRequest` object in action class?

```
@MadvocAction(value = "login")
public class LoginAction extends BaseAction {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @PetiteInject
    UserService userService;

    @Action
    public void view() {
        if (logger.isInfoEnabled())
            logger.info("LoginAction.view()");
       // Code for getting ip Address
        forwardTo("/login.jsp");
    }
}
```

Comment: Make a field for a HttpServletRequest and then pass it to the Login class with setter method.

Comment: Hello mastah, I am using Jodd Madvoc MVC Framework in which I haven't to initialize the action class. So setting private field of HttpServletRequest is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading http://jodd.org/doc/madvoc/injection.html like `HttpServletResponse` injection I have done the same for `HttpServletRequest`.

```
@MadvocAction(value = "login")
public class LoginAction extends BaseAction {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @PetiteInject
    UserService userService;

    @In(scope = ScopeType.SERVLET)
    protected HttpServletResponse servletResponse;

    @In(scope = ScopeType.SERVLET)
    protected HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    @Action
    public void view() {
        if (logger.isInfoEnabled())
            logger.info("LoginAction.view()");
       // Code for getting ip Address
        forwardTo("/login.jsp");
    }
}
```

And problem is solved. :-)

Comment: This is correct answer :) However, try not to use servlet class - Madvoc purpose is so users may use simple java beans, and not servlet classes. In your case, do the forwarding using the results - just keep reading the docs ;)))

Comment: Yes I am trying not to use HttpServletRequest but I want to get Ip Address from request so want to use that.

Comment: Got it. Notice that you can reach servlet properties (like getRequestAddress) using special fields names... from the docs: "...adapter map for servlet objects: when @In property is named as: requestMap, sessionMap or contextMap, corresponding map adapter will be injected in the property. Of course, it is expected that property type is Map...."